# C# serial For --> parallel For: results are jumbled

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

this may be a somewhat basic question (and I have to admit, I'm not very experienced with parallel programming).

I've written a single threaded C# program during which an array `p` of parameters is created, then each parameter `p[i]`  is evaluated with a function `f`, and the pair `( p[i], f( p[i] ) )` of each evaluation is then placed into a Heap (which gets sorted by function value). Very roughly, it looks like this:

```cs
class Agent {
  private double[] parameter;
  private double value;

  public Agent( double[] par, double val ) { this.parameter = par; this.val = value; }
}

class Work {

  public void optimise() {

    // return an array of parameters, each one of which is a double array itself
    double[][] parameter = getParameters();
    Agent[] results = new Agent[ parameter.Length ];

    for ( int idx = 0; idx < parameter.Length; idx++ )
      results[ idx ] = new Agent( parameter[idx], cost_function( parameter[ idx ] ) );

  }

  private double cost_function( double[] par ) {

    // evaluate par, get result
    return result;

  }
}
```

Since the evaluation of `cost_function` is rather lengthy, and `parameter` is long, I thought about paralleising that, portioning the contents of `parameter` into segments, and then using `Parallel.For` on each segment. Rather naively, I changed routine `optimise` into this:

```cs
  public void optimise() {

    // select an appropriate number of threads, e.g.
    int number_of_threads = Environment.ProcessorCount;

    // return an array of parameters, each one of which is a double array itself
    double[][] parameter = getParameters();

    // split the array of parameters into #number_of_threads many 
    // segments (of roughly equal size)
    double[][][] par_segments = distribute_parameter( parameter );

    Agent[][] results = new Agent[ number_of_threads ];


    // process each segment in an individual thread
    Parallel.For( 0, number_of_threads, idx => {

      results[ idx ] = new Agent[ par_segments[ idx ].Length ];
      for ( int agent = 0; agent < par_segments[ idx ].Length; agent++ )
        results[ idx ][ agent ] = 
          new Agent( par_segments[ idx ][ agent ], cost_function( par_segments[ idx ][ agent ] );
    } );
  }
```

My naive expectation was, that, for each segment (ie each `idx`), the interior of would be handled consistently, in particular, that in the creation of each `new Agent( p, cost_function( p ) )`, the two `p` in that expression would be identical, and that the resulting `Agent` would indeed contain a corresponding pair of parameter and function value. But what I get instead is `new Agent( p1, cost_function( p2 ) )`, and I'm don't even think `p2` neccessarily is a part of the original `parameter` array.

The `Parallel.For` routine works fine if I lock the last statement in it, but of course that rather makes parallelisation useless.
Is there any better way to ensure that the results matrix will be filled with consistent parameter/value pairs that doesn't require changes to the original `cost_function` routine?

If so, is there a good online resource that explains this? And final question: what would be a good book on the topic?

Thanks in advance!
Best, Rob

Comment: Your thinking is on track as far as I can tell. That is, it is OK to use an output array like you do. The second parameter to Parallel.For should be the output array length, not core count. Given your problem description, it could be that your cost function is somehow affected by shared state. (This could happen if you reuse a cached list stored in a member variable).

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan Thanks for your reply! I may have misunderstood the role of the of the index in `Parallel.For` - I thought a thread per index number would be created. I'll have to check on that again.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without the complete code te grasp it, but i think you mean something like this:

```
var result = from parameter in parameters.AsParallel()
             select new Agent(parameter, cost_function( parameter));
```

Comment: Beware that 'AsParallel()' randomizes the output order.